# How do I print the result of a command with 'echo'?

Tags: bash, echo

How do print my full name with the following?

```
awk -F: '($1==U){print $5}' U=$LOGNAME /etc/passwd
```

Per example, but with the `echo` command with some words on sides:

For example,

> Hello Diogo Saraiva, happy to see you again

Where Diogo Saraiva is my full name which I have in Ubuntu records.
I tried some things, but I have not accomplished that script...

**Another thing:** Why, when I issue `awk -F: '($1==U){print $5}' U=$LOGNAME /etc/passwd`, is `Diogo Saraiva,,,` shown instead of `Diogo Saraiva`?

This happens too with:

```
grep $USER /etc/passwd | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } { print $5 }'
```

I need for my script to declare a variable, "like", with the command, and then echo that variable "like" various times along my script.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To output the string you want you can use this command.

```
awk -F: -v U="$LOGNAME" '$1==U{print "Hello " $5 ", happy to see you again"}' /etc/passwd
```

If `awk -F: -v U="$LOGNAME" '$1==U{print $5}' /etc/passwd` is outputting `Diogo Saraiva,,,` then that is what is in your `/etc/passwd` file for that field.

To save the output from a command in a variable just use:

```
var=$(command)
```

And remember to quote the variable when you use it:

```
echo "Hello $var, happy to see you again"
```

Comment: echo $(ls /home/xx)